# Can't import views.py into urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Just started working with Django. I created an app, mapped it on INSTALLED_APPS list and wrote a simple function in views.py. I tried to import views in urls.py but I'am getting an error: Cannot find reference 'views' in '**init**.py'

views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

urls.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from homepage import views #<---GETTING AN ERROR RIGHT HERE

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Share the error... (the full traceback)

Comment: Can you also share the `__init__.py` of your app?

Comment: All of my __init__.py in project are empty. Also where can I find the full traceback because I couldn't find it on terminal.

Comment: Please post your directory structure. It looks like you have `views.py` in app directory and try to import it from `urls.py` in "management" directory (near `manage.py`). Solution will be set up url configuration according to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you did all this steps:**

1 - created your app using `python manage.py startapp projectApp` or `django-admin startapp projectApp`

2 - added your app name `projectApp` to installed apps

3 - create urls.py file for your new app

**In your views.py file**

```
  def home_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
      return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**In Urls.py file**

```
from .views import home_page


app_name = 'projectAppName'
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Add You app urls name to your main project directory/path urls.py file**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('home/', include('projectApp.urls', namespace='projectAppName')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
from .views import home_page
```

If this does not work, then create a class in `views.py` and then put a function into the class and then import it. E.g.,

**`views.py`**

```py
class Home(View):
    def home_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
     return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from views import Home
```